# Why does JRuby Swing app quits immediately if run as jar

Tags: java, swing, jruby, warbler

I am trying to build a simple JRuby application with a GUI. I am using the code in [this page](http://zetcode.com/gui/jrubyswing/introduction/) as a starting point, section marked "Simple Example".

If I take the code snippet and I run it as

```
$> jruby test.rb
```

then it is all fine, I see the window.

If I try to make a "jar" file and run it with:

```
$> warble jar
$> java -jar test.jar
```

Then the application immediately exists without leaving an error code.

I tried to run the "jar" file in Windows10 and FreeBSD11.2, same behaviour, the GUI immediately quits.

Do you know how can I work around this ?
Sorry for the simple question, these are my first steps with JRuby.

Comment: Main thread ends after `Example.new`. Invoke it with a new thread and SwingUtilities. The repl acts as a main thread when you run it as a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

After Elliott suggestion I made the following modification to the last line of the original code and the "jar" works. It is just a hack, but small enough to get a beginner, like me, on track;)

```
t1 = Thread.new {
   Example.new
}

while true do
  sleep 1
end
```